# game high score purpose. Javascript

Tags: javascript

in 1st html

```
function stopTyping(){
clearInterval(timer1);
wordChars = [];
wordArea.textContent = "";
typeArea.textContent = "";
**scoreArea.textContent = "Score: " + score;
if(score >= hs)
{
hs=score; 
localStorage.setItem('hs' , hs); 
}**
startButton.hidden = true;
wordArea.hidden = true;
typeArea.hidden = true;
}
```

other html

```
document.getElementById("Easy1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('hs');
```

Here is my current code. I just want my highscore to remain in "other html" but whenever i get lower than my highscore, it record the lower one... 
Help please.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is the only place in the code where you set the localStorage?

Comment: Yes sir. SLR @gil.neo

Comment: The logic is simple and it shouldn't happen. Maybe "score >= hs" is comparing strings instead of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
score = parseInt(score); 
hs = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('hs'));
if(score >= hs) {
  hs = score;
  localStorage.setItem('hs', score);
}
```